# The maximal order of an element in a Coxeter group

Tags: finite-groups, coxeter-groups

Let $W$ be a finite Coxeter group. Let
$$
N_W=\operatorname{max}_{g\in W}\operatorname{ord}(g)
$$
where $\operatorname{ord}(g)$ denotes the order of an element  $g$. By Fermat's little theorem, we know that $N_W$ divides the order of $W$. What else can we say about $N_W$? Is $N_W$ related to the Coxeter number of $W$?

Comment: For the symmetric group see http://oeis.org/A000793.

Comment: Let it be $f(n)$ for $S_n$. So in type $A_n$ it's $f(n+1)$. In type $B_n=C_n$ (perm. wreath product $C_2\wr S_n$) for $n\ge 2$, say we get $h(n)$. Then $f(n)\le h(n)\le 2f(n)$. If $f(n)$ is even we get $2f(n)$ by an easy argument. The OEIS list suggests the only exception is $n=8$ for which $f(n)=15$. But $S_8$ has an element of order $12$ and then $h(8)=24$. So if indeed $f(n)$ is even for all $n\ge 9$, then  $h(n)=2f(n)$ for all $8\neq n\ge 2$.

Comment: The Coxeter number of $S_m$ is neither $m!$ nor $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$.  It is $m$.  (Every Coxeter element of $S_m$ is an $m$-cycle, so the order of a Coxeter element is $m$.)  The numbers $m!$ and $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ are, respectively, the order of $S_m$ and the number of reflections (or positive roots) in $S_m$.

Comment: @NathanReading Ah yes, I got my notation mixed up. Landau proved that for $S_n$ we have $H_W \sim O(n \ln n)$, and since the Coxeter number is $n$, we have evidence that there isn't an obvious relation.

Comment: Maybe, I should ask this as a different question. But do you know the LCM of all orders as well, i.e. the smallest positive integer $N$ such that $g^N=1$ for all $g\in W$? We still have $N\leq|W|$ (maybe even division). For Coxeter number, you have $\frac{2|T|}{|S|}$. So, you are right, Nathan.

Comment: Looks like the new number $N$ is the LCM of $(1,\ldots,m)$ for $\mathbb{S}_m$ which is divisible by $N_{\mathbb{S}_m}$ and divides the order (but both divisions might not be equal). I wonder if that is true for every finite $W$...

Comment: I haven't verified for $S_m$ that $N$ is the LCM of $(1,\ldots,m)$, but if so, you should think of it as the LCM of $(2,\ldots,m)$.  That suggests a general question:  For a finite Coxeter group $W$, is the smallest positive integer $N$ such that $w^N=1$ for all $w\in W$ equal to the LCM of the degrees of $W$ (or equivalently, the LCM of $(e_i+1:i=1,\ldots,\mathrm{rank}(W))$, where the $e_i$ are the exponents of $W$)?

Comment: @NathanReading: looks like it: http://www.findstat.org/St001157